# Is it possible to put transparent webview over videoview android 2.1+?

Tags: android, webview, transparency, overlay, android-videoview

tried to put toast notification with webview over videoview?? I tryed to use FrameLayout but webview always under video...! And mb can anybody give me advice how to put dynamic text content over videoview? Thanks!